# Multithreaded sorting of Lists of Generic Type

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, generics

We need to Define a Tools class which contains the following static generic methods:
a. parallelSort which takes one parameter of type ArrayList and returns a sorted
version of the parameter list without modifying it:

1. Divide the list into two parts and make a copy of each
2. Start two threads by making instances of SortingThread where each thread
   sorts one of the copies obtained in the previous step
3. Merge the results generated by the two threads

I am Getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: 
arraycopy: source type java.util.ArrayList is not an array
at 
java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
```

this is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tools {

    
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> parallelSort(ArrayList<T> arr){
        
        //Obtaining the first Half and making a copy of it
        ArrayList<T> FirstHalf = new ArrayList<T>(arr.size()/2);
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, FirstHalf, 0, arr.size()/2);
        
        //Obtaining the second Half and making a copy of it
        ArrayList<T> SecondHalf = new ArrayList<T>(arr.size()- (arr.size()/2));
        System.arraycopy(arr, arr.size()/2, SecondHalf, 0, arr.size()- (arr.size()/2));
        
        
        //Creating Thread
        SortingThread<T> thread1 = new SortingThread<T>();
        //Start Thread
        thread1.start(); //Creating Thread parallelSort
        
        //Creating Thread
        SortingThread<T> thread2 = new SortingThread<T>();
        //Start Thread
        thread2.start(); 
        
        
        return arr;
        
    }
    
    public static <T> boolean areEqual(ArrayList<T> arr1, ArrayList<T> arr2) {
        
        return arr1.equals(arr2);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Testing on list of complex numbers
        Complex c1= new Complex(3,4);
        Complex c2= new Complex(2,2);
        Complex c3= new Complex(1,2);
        ArrayList<Complex> a1= new ArrayList<Complex>();
        a1.add(c1);
        a1.add(c2);
        a1.add(c3);
        
        
        
        System.out.println("The Original two lists:");
        System.out.println(a1);
    
        System.out.print(Tools.parallelSort(a1));
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception states it clearly. Java is a **strongly** types language. So you can't use **array list** in a place of **array** . Obviously **arraycopy()** method only supports array type not Lists.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.System#arrayCopy` method accepts an array type as its first and third arguments.

You should transform your input `ArrayList` to and array before copying its items using the `#toArray` method:

```
ArrayList<T> FirstHalf = new ArrayList<T>(arr.size()/2)
System.arraycopy(arr.toArray(), 0, FirstHalf.toArray(), 0, arr.size()/2);
```

Meanwhile, this would leave your `FirstHalf` list useless, as:

1. the `#toArray` method returns a array that is not referenced by any means from the original `ArrayList`
2. the destination array will be off index when accessed as it holds no element

I recommend then that you review your implementation to either use arrays from entry to result (transforming the latter to an `ArrayList`) at the end or use another approach such as:

```
ArrayList<T> FirstHalf = new ArrayList<T>(arr.size()/2);
Object [] temp = new Object[arr.size()/2];
System.arraycopy(arr.toArray(), 0, temp, 0, arr.size()/2);
FirstHalf.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Is there any easier way to approach it, I can't change the parameter of parallelSort() as it is required in the question for it to be as an ArrayList<T>. I did as you told me but it is still giving this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: last destination index 2 out of bounds for object array[0]
 at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at Tools.parallelSort(Tools.java:20)
 at Tools.main(Tools.java:59)

Comment: Would you update the main OP with your updated method? If you followed the approach I mentioned it could not lead such an error unless the input list if of size 0.